# FFMpeg installation in Ubuntu 12.04 and using it in PHP-FFMpeg

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I have tried many many failed attempt to install FFMpeg in my Ubuntu 12.04.
I used following links: [1](http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm), [2](http://blog.shineservers.com/installing-and-configuring-ffmpeg-and-ffpeg-php/), [3](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/install-ffmpeg) and many others.

Then I need to use it in [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)
And Then I need to deploy in Linux based server. This is my requirement.

But after much trying, I just downloaded static build through this [link](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

This helped me to successfully convert video and use FFMpeg through terminal in Ubuntu. But I cannot use it through PHP-FFMpeg library **which I need to run**. In docs of PHP-FFMpeg it is written

> This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both
>   FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. Be sure that these binaries can
>   be located with system PATH to get the benefit of the binary
>   detection, otherwise you should have to explicitely give the binaries
>   path on load.

and I am not getting this.

Comment: you want to install Ffmpeg in ubuntu or centos?

Comment: Right now I need to install it in Ubuntu 12.04 and  then on Linux based web server (Which linux based server? That information is not provided to me right now)

Comment: Are you tried this link http://josesantiagojr.com/post/41299188705/install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-from-source

Comment: No, Have you tried? Does it give successful installation of FFMpeg?

Comment: i have not tried,i have tried in centos,that is working fine.can i give that link?

Comment: This link for centos http://root.uabid.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-centos-6-x/

Comment: Thanks very much. It helped me. That worked successfully.  It installed FFMpeg in Ubuntu and it is working, but I am still having problem running PHP-FFMpeg. Error is : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException' with message 'ffprobe failed to execute command '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe' '-help' '-loglevel' 'quiet'' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpi/ffmpeg2/ffmpeg/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php ... in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpi/ffmpeg2/ffmpeg/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe/OptionsTester.php on line 63

Comment: ok for your reference just i am added answer,just see that link and php code also.

Comment: Converted links properly and some formatting.